# youtube API - playing videoSyndicated vs videoEmbeddable

Tags: uiwebview, youtube-api

Not sure of the terminology here, so excuse me if the title is misleading. I'm new to the YouTube API and trying to understand it and how to use it to play videos in my app. I have some code that that uses `iframe` `embeds` to play videos. Of course content like music videos is being blocked by this.

So I tried this - I shared a music video directly from youtube.com to my Facebook feed. I opened the Facebook app and clicked on this post and it navigated to what looks like a standard UIWebView:

[image]

When I click the video it opens up into a full-screen media player (not sure what this class is called, I've never worked with it), and played fine.

---

So two questions:

- How can I check if a video is playable embedded in an `iFrame` and how can I check if I need to actually bring up the youtube page like the Facebook app? Is the former `videoSyndicated` and the latter `videoEmbeddable`?
- And so is this Facebook method just a UIWebView loaded with youtube.com directed towards whatever particular video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syndication is effectively irrelevant here. (It controlled whether playback was allowed on certain TV devices and older mobile YouTube applications.)

Whether a video is embeddable is what you care about with regard to iframe embedded playback. (Ideally you'd be checking this with the [`video.status.embeddable`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) property using the Data API v3.) There are some wrinkles to this rule outlined in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html).

Your second question is about displaying m.youtube.com in a UIWebView. While this is obviously possible (since m.youtube.com is just a web page), it's not something that we encourage developers to do when integrating YouTube playback into their iOS applications.